# How do I install the piFace Control & Display

Tags: apt, piface

I bought one of [these](http://uk.farnell.com/piface/piface-control-display/i-o-board-with-lcd-display-for/dp/2344458) (PiFace Control & Display) and according to the online instructions [here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1765332.pdf), it says to run:

```
apt-get install python3-pifacecad
```

but when I do that I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pifacecad
```

I've checked my repositiories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and they match the repositories listed [here](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository).

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

I've also run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`. What else do I need to do? I'm running raspian wheezy but it is a scaled down (minimalized) version which I got from [here](https://www.linuxsystems.it/raspbian-wheezy-armhf-raspberry-pi-minimal-image/). Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Did you try to add the publickey? "wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian.public.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -"

Comment: @Simon, i just tried your suggestion, but i still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I did manage to get this working, but only by cloning the project directly from github.

Even then I still had further problems relating to dependencies which were incorrect. The python code seems to reference a `lirc` module which doesn't seem to exist. I did find a `pylirc` module which I installed with `apt-get install python-pylirc`.

Ultimately I had to change references in the source python that read `import lirc` to `import pylirc as lirc`, apparently because the name of the dependency changed since the code was last updated(??)

EDIT: Aha! This seemed to help me get the original distro according to the user manual:

```
echo "deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
wget http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/raspberrypi.gpg.key
apt-key add raspberrypi.gpg.key
apt-get update
```

Then I was able to:

```
apt-get install python{,3}-pifacecad
```

which installs the proper dependency: `python-lirc` among others.

Comment: This line gives an error for me, echo "deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: What error? You probably don't have write access to the sources.list file.  These commands should be preceded by sudo in almost all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Posting on this ancient question because it is *still* or *again* an issue with PiFace Control and Display boards purchased recently.

I had success with installing the python module using `pip` to install it straight from GutHub:

`pip3 install git+https://github.com/piface/pifacecad.git`

You'll need to install the pre-requisites ( `git+https://github.com/piface/pifacecommon.git` and `lirc`) as well.

References:

- https://github.com/piface/pifacecad
- https://github.com/piface/pifacecad/issues/33