# How do i install pifacecad?

Tags: piface, source.list, repository

I have tried the work found [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14116/how-do-i-install-the-piface-control-display), but the line below gives me errors, when I run `sudo apt-get update`.

```
echo "deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

What can I do to get the pifacecad installed? Is there a deb package I can get? Or source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing because in [the answer to that other question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/14219/5538), Octopus was working as `root`.  You need privileges to edit `sources.list`, and this kind of thing:

```
sudo echo "whatever" >> /only/root/can/write/file
```

Won't work because of the `>>` redirection.  The `echo` runs `sudo`, but the redirection is done by your shell, which does not.  To get around this, you can use:

- `sudoedit` on `sources.list` and add the line.
- `su root`, then when you're done, `exit`.
- `sudo bash`, then when you're done, `exit`.